# Clean in Eclipse removes WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml file

Tags: eclipse, persistence.xml, jpa-2.1

I have a dynamic web project in Eclipse LUNA

Its targeted to run on Glassfish4

I am using JPA2.1 with Hibernate

My `persistence.xml` file needs to be loacted here

```
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

however every time I refresh then clean my project Eclipse removes the `META-INF` folder.

What am I doing wrong?